# Interest rate modelling: Iterated extended kalman filter with Maximum Likelihood

Tags: matlab, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation, kalman-filter

I recently started to deepen my knowledge about interest rates' modelling, and I am trying to estimate a two-factor Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process using Euro area OIS rates by means of an Iterated extended Kalman filter with Maximum Likelihood estimation.

Without entering into the details of the model, I have a conceptual doubt regarding the Extended Kalman filter.
From what I understood, given a set of initial parameters' estimates (some initial guesses), the filter allows us to improve those estimates, giving us a final set of estimated parameters (according to some tolerance we may specify).

My question is quite simple: if I use the final set of parameters I obtain from a first estimation of the model as initial guesses for a second estimation of the model, that is I repeat the estimation of my model using as initial parameters the final ones previously estimated, should I expect to find a (new) final parameters set that is very similar, if not equal, to the initial one?

I am asking this because my algorithm provides me with substantially different estimates and I am trying to figure out why.

Probably this may sound a bit silly to most of you, but as I mentioned before I am quite new in this area and I am trying to grasp some fundamental concepts.

Thank you!

Comment: The parameters that you are trying to estimate are constant? Does your model have states that do change over time? Namely, extended Kalman filters can give wrong results if your initial guess is too far off from the true value.

Comment: Hi Kwin, thank you for your comment. Yes, the parameters of the model I am trying to estimate are constant, and they instruct two state variables which change overtime. In facts, the state variables are described by a discretization of a Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process, that is equivalent to a VAR.  Am I wrong to think that with a good initial guess I can improve the extended Kalman filter estimates by repeating the estimation several times with "updated" initial guesses?

Comment: Without further analysis of the system dynamics it is hard to say. Namely, if your initial guess is bad than it might very well be possible that any further iterations might only diverge further and further from the actual value. However, it might also be possible to prove that iterating does always converges to a global minimum. I am not familiar with the model you mentioned, so my guess now would be it could go either way.

Comment: From my repeated estimates it seems like parameters converge at a minimum value. This makes me think my initial guess may be good. Thank you very much!